# Cosine similarity of one vector with many

Tags: performance, r, clustering

I'm keen to hear ideas for optimising R code to compute the cosine similarity of a vector `x` (with length `l`) with `n` other vectors (stored in any structure such as a matrix `m` with `n` rows and `l` columns).

Values for `n` will typically be much larger than values for `l`.

I'm currently using this custom Rcpp function to compute the similarity of a vector `x` to each row of a matrix `m`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector cosine_x_to_m(NumericVector x, NumericMatrix m) {
  int nrows = m.nrow();
  NumericVector out(nrows);
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    NumericVector y = m(i, _);
    out[i] = sum(x * y) / sqrt(sum(pow(x, 2.0)) * sum(pow(y, 2.0)));
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Varying `n` and `l`, I'm getting the following sorts of timings:

[image]

Reproducible code below.

---

```
# Function to simulate data
sim_data <- function(l, n) {
  # Feature vector to be used for computing similarity
  x <- runif(l)

  # Matrix of feature vectors (1 per row) to compare against x
  m <- matrix(runif(n * l), nrow = n)

  list(x = x, m = m)
}

# Rcpp function to compute similarity of x to each row of m
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector cosine_x_to_m(NumericVector x, NumericMatrix m) {
  int nrows = m.nrow();
  NumericVector out(nrows);
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    NumericVector y = m(i, _);
    out[i] = sum(x * y) / sqrt(sum(pow(x, 2.0)) * sum(pow(y, 2.0)));
  }
  return out;
}')    

# Timer function
library(microbenchmark)
timer <- function(l, n) {
  dat <- sim_data(l, n)
  microbenchmark(cosine_x_to_m(dat$x, dat$m))
}

# Results for grid of l and n
library(tidyverse)
results <- cross_d(list(l = seq(200, 1000, by = 200), n = seq(500, 4000, by = 500))) %>% 
  mutate(timings = map2(l, n, timer))

# Plot results
results_plot <- results %>%
  unnest(timings) %>% 
  mutate(time = time / 1000000) %>%  # Convert time to seconds
  group_by(l, n) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(time), ci = 1.96 * sd(time) / sqrt(n()))

pd <- position_dodge(width = 20)

results_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n, mean, group= l)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(l)), position = pd, size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - ci, ymax = mean + ci), position = pd, width = 100) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 2) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "n", y = "Seconds", color = "l") +
  ggtitle("Algorithm Runtime",
          subtitle = "Error bars represent 95% confidence intervals")
```

Comment: On the 'code review' side of things, I have a few comments.

Comment: You calculate `sum(pow(x, 2.0))` within the loop, even though it does not change.

Comment: The use of `pow` function for squaring numbers is inefficient. Simple `x*x` is faster.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin I checked it with gcc 6.2.0 and could not find any "significant" difference between `std::pow(x, 2)`, `std::pow(x, 2.0)` and `x * x` in terms of speed. Might be different of older compiler versions, e.g., http://martin-ueding.de/en/articles/efficiency-of-pow-function/index.html.

Comment: @Dominik, thanks, I stand corrected. 
Did you try using a fast BLAS (i.e. Microsoft R)? It was the core of the performance improvement I've got.

Comment: @Dominik, also, I suggest flipping the order of the loops in your version of rowSumsSq.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin I did not try with Microsoft R, but I would not expect performance gains as there are no matrix operations involved here (my "answer" only concerns the function `rowSums`, not the part including the matrix multiplication). What do you mean by flipping loop order? Rows within columns is just the reason for the speed imrovement I got.

Comment: But your algorithm uses matrix multiplication and matrix multiplication can be done much faster.

Comment: Ok, disregard my comment about the loops, I ran the tests, the results are not supporting my expectations.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 4 → 1.

Comment: Right, thanks @200_success. I've now posted my solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Microsoft R (with Intel MKL) which makes matrix multiplications faster, but for fair comparison I set it to be single threaded.

```
setMKLthreads(1)
```

In my tests this pure R version `cosine_x_to_m` is twice faster than yours.

```
cosine_x_to_m2 = function(x,m){
  x = x / sqrt(crossprod(x));
  return(  as.vector((m %*% x) / sqrt(rowSums(m^2))) );
}
```

Rewriting `rowSums(m^2)` in C/C++ makes it even faster, about four times faster than the original.

```
library(ramwas)
cosine_x_to_m2 = function(x,m){
  x = x / sqrt(crossprod(x));
  return(  as.vector((m %*% x) / sqrt(rowSumsSq(m))) );
}
```

Initial performance:

[image: Initial performance]

Final version performance:

[image: Final version performance]

Comment: Thanks, this has helped a huge amount! I tweaked a few things (based on your comments too) and used custom functions instead of ramwas::rowSumsSq (which I had trouble installing). I've added my updated solution in answer.

Comment: I can get you this function separately from the rest of the package, but it seems you are doing well without it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, but there is still some room for simplification and decent improvement in the function `rowSumsSq`. The reason is that due to the column-major order of matrices in memory, looping over rows within columns is more effecient than vice versa.

```
library('Rcpp')
n <- m <- 1000L
dat <- matrix(rnorm(n*m), nrow = n, ncol = m)

cppFunction('NumericVector rowSumsSq_faster(NumericMatrix x) {

  int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out(nrow);

  for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j) {
      for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
          out[i] += std::pow(x(i, j), 2);
      }
  }

  return out;
}')
```

A quick benchmark gives

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 1e3L,
                           rowSums(dat^2),
                           rowSumsSq(dat),
                           rowSumsSq_faster(dat)
)

Unit: microseconds
              expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq
rowSums(dat^2) 4573.501 4691.8010 5830.381 4764.6240 5522.5845
rowSumsSq(dat) 1778.245 1855.7020 1886.566 1877.0595 1906.5605
rowSumsSq_faster(dat)  799.546  852.5835  869.913  865.1385  879.8275
```

Comment: This is a really great addition! Thanks. I've added it into my updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers and comments from @Andrey and @Dominik, I implemented the code below. A solid improvement ~ 60% better!

```
## C++ functions to offload matrix calculations
# Sum of squares for each row of a matrix
cppFunction('NumericVector rowSumsSq(NumericMatrix x) {
  int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out(nrow);

  for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
      out[i] += std::pow(x(i, j), 2);
    }
  }

  return out;
}')

# Compute cosine similarity of vector x to each row in matrix m
cosine_x_to_m  <- function(x, m) {
  x <- x / sqrt(crossprod(x))
  as.vector(m %*% x / sqrt(rowSumsSq(m)))
}
```

Using same timing and plotting functions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting a final solution. I have two further comments. First, `crossprod(x)` will be faster than `sum(x * x)`. Second, your function `mxMult` is not necessary, simply replace it by `m %*% x` and your code will be as fast or even faster.  In my experience, it is impossible to beat `crossprod`, `tcrossprod`, `%*%` by anything hand-written in Rcpp. Just try for fun of it to implement full matrix mutliplication `%*%` in Rcpp by three nested for loops and I would bet it will be way slower.

Comment: And it just keeps getting better! I've updated answer. Thanks :)